# Почему код не работает, пока нет лишнего вывода cout. C++

Tags: c++

Недавно начал учить с++, выполнял задачу №9 на leetcode:

> Given an integer x, return true if x is a palindrome, and false otherwise.
>
> > Учитывая целое число x, вернуть true, если x является палиндромом, и false в противном случае. -*Google translate*

Вроде бы мой код должен работать, но почему-то при вводе числа 123, вместо false выводит true,
но если после оператора if который проверяет, равно ли перевернутое число исходному, добавить cout (в коде выделен как комментарий) который будет выводить что угодно, код работает правильно.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = x;
        bool res;

        if(x < 0)
        {
            res = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(b%10 != 0)
            {
                while(b>0)
                {
                    a=a*10+b%10;
                    b /= 10;
                }
                if(a == x)
                {
//                    cout << "<- код не работает без этого.";
                    res = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(x<10)
                {
                    res = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего из-за того, что переменная `bool res;` изначально не инициализирована и у вас есть ветка, при которой она так и не получает значение, получилось UB - и компилятор сделал оптимизацию - выкинул эту ветку вообще. А когда вы ставите туда оператор вывода в поток, эта ветка условия остается, выкинуть её не получается. Решение - инициализируйте переменную вначале.
Ещё из практики - изначально инициализируете переменную `bool res = false;`, а далее в коде отрабатываете только те ветки, где необходимо поменять значение на `true`.
P.S. много вложений, код не читабельный. Можно сделать более линейно и вообще не используя `res`:

```
bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = x;
        
        if(x < 0)
            return false;
      
        if(b%10 == 0)
        if(x<10)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
        
        while(b>0)
        {
            a=a*10+b%10;
            b /= 10;
        }
        
        if(a == x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ошибка в том что у тебя там нет ветки else, ты типо проверяешь равны ли полученные числа но если не равны не выставляешь res в true, в самом начале он у тебя тоже не инициализирован, как вариант ты после цикла можешь сделать так
res = a == x
либо поставить else и res = false

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = x;
        bool res;

        if(x < 0)
        {
            res = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(b%10 != 0)
            {
                while(b>0)
                {
                    a=a*10+b%10;
                    b /= 10;
                }
                res = a == x;
            }
            else
            {
                if(x<10)
                {
                    res = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
     }
};
```

а вообще в следующий раз дропай весь код, так чуток проще
P.S. поставь вывод всех ошибок они обычно полезные

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в буферизации вывода. То есть код работает, но другой код не отправляет данные на экран, а ждёт, когда заполнится буфер. Поэтому после завершения вывода каждой строки надо выводить std::endl, даже если эта строка последняя. Если строка кончилась по факту и произошёл перенос на следующую без Вашего явного ан то указания, то std::endl не нужен, но если в данном месте конец строки должен быть обязательно, то надо std::endl. А последняя строка должна закончиться обязательно.